# Problem using custom package

Tags: mac, texshop, mactex, package-writing, texpad

The problems occur with the following two example files.

---

The first file is called `sty1.sty`. It is located in

```
~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/packages/sty1
```

I created all of the folders below `~/Library`.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{sty1}

\RequirePackage{showframe}
```

When I try to typeset it with Texpad, I get the error `Undefined control sequence` for lines 1, 2, 4. TeXShop does not show any errors.

---

The second file is called `test.tex`. It is located in my iCloud Drive.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{sty1}

\begin{document}
Content.
\end{document}
```

When I try to typeset it with Texpad, I get `LaTeX error: File 'sty1.sty' not found`. Again, TeXShop does not show any errors.

Comment: Where is TeXPad looking for files? Is it set up to use the same TeX distribution as TeXShop? Have you installed TeX Live (via MacTeX)?

Comment: Perhaps https://www.texpad.com/support/tex/texpadtex/texpadtex-custom-packages can help. I've never used TeXPad.  I'm assuming you're running it on iOS (iPad/iPhone) not MacOS?

Comment: @AlanMunn : there is a version of TeXPad for MacOS. I’ve never used it but I believe it can either use TeX Live or some proprietary distribution. I know nothing about the latter.

Comment: @AlanMunn I am running Texpad on MacOS. I tried using the solution you provided. That is, I added my `~/Library/texmf` folder to Shared Files. However, it still cannot find them.